# linq aggregate

Tags: linq, aggregate

```
class Category
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set;}
}


Name Count
AA   2
BB   3
AA   4
```

I have an `IEnumerable<Category>`

and would like to get a list of Categories with unique names and the sum of multiple entries

**Output**

```
Name Count
AA   6
BB   3
```

**Update**

```
class Category 
{ 
public string Name { get; set; } 
public int CountA { get; set;} 
public int CountB { get; set;} 
public string Phone { get; set;} 
}
```

How would I sum two columns. and the phone column can be the last row or any row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var foo = new List<Category>() { 
                new Category() { Name = "AA", Count = 2},
                new Category() { Name = "BB", Count = 3},
                new Category() { Name = "AA", Count = 4}
            };

            var bar = foo.GroupBy(c => c.Name).Select(g => new Category(){ Name = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(c => c.Count) });
```

Comment: class Category
    {        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CountA { get; set;}
        public int CountB { get; set;}
        public string Phone { get; set;}
    }

How would I sum two columns. and the phone column can be the last row or any row

Answer (score 5):

Your updated question isn't entirely clear in terms of the phone number, but I suspect you want something like:

```
    var query = from category in list
                group category by category.Name into grouped
                select new { Name = grouped.Key,
                             SumA = grouped.Sum(x => x.CountA),
                             SumB = grouped.Sum(x => x.CountB),
                             Phone = grouped.Last().Phone };
```

Changing `grouped.Last()` to `grouped.First()` would be more efficient, by the way.

Evaluating multiple aggregates in this way isn't terribly efficient in general. The [Push LINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/01/04/quot-push-quot-linq-revisited-next-attempt-at-an-explanation.aspx) project developed by myself and Marc Gravell makes it a lot more efficient at the cost of not being quite as easy to use. You might want to look into it if you need to deal with a lot of data.